# Como chamar uma função PHP específica com AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Preciso chamar uma função específica dentro de um arquivo PHP com AJAX. Tentei de várias formas, fiz pesquisas até mesmo aqui no *Stack*, mas não rola de jeito nenhum.

O que estou fazendo:

Código PHP:

```
$functionName = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'functionName');

if (isset($_GET['functionName']) && !empty($_GET['functionName'])) {

    $functionName = $_GET['functionName'];

    switch ($functionName) {
        case 'getInscritos': 
            getInscritos(); 
        break;
    }

}

public function getInscritos() {

$datas = array();

    $vagas = get_post_meta($this->id, InscricoesPostType::ID . '_vagas');
    $ins = get_post_meta($this->id, InscricoesPostType::ID . '_inscritos');

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $datas[] = array(
            'vagas' => $vagas[$key],
            'inscritos' => $ins[$key]
        );
    }

    return json_encode(get_post_meta($this->id, InscricoesPostType::ID . '_vagas'));
}
```

Código JS:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/../dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/arquivo.php',
                data: "functionName=getInscritos",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('Função encontrada' + data);
                },
                error: function(data){ 
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log('Função não encontrada: ' + obj); 
                }
            });
```

Comment: 1) Por quê você utiliza `filter_input` para o obter o valor do parâmetro filtrado, mas depois o obtém diretamente? Isso não fez muito sentido; 2) Sua função `getInscritos` possui um termo de encapsulamento `public` em sua definição, o que dá a entender que é um método de uma classe, então poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o **código completo** da classe? 3) Quando este código JS é executado, logo que carrega a página ou em algum evento do JS? 4) Por quê, na função `getInscritos`, você utiliza a variável `$data`, mas esta não faz parte do retorno da função?

Comment: Creio que uma das coisas que você possa estar errando é isso aqui: 
data: "functionName=getInscritos"... Você tá passando de forma errada, sendo que deveria ser assim: data: { functionName: "getInscritos" }.